# HandlebarsJs Nodejs and JWT

Tags: node.js, jwt, handlebars.js

I'm trying to do the authentication with JWT in Server using Nodejs and Handlebarjs, but the problem is I generated the JWT on server side, rendered and saved it into localStorage in Handlebarjs but when the middleware check for the token, it showed undefined even though when I checked the localStorage, it in there. Any suggestion?

Backend Code:

```
            const tokenUser = {user: existingUser._id}
            
            const token = jwt.sign(tokenUser, 'gmndshhrjvjhsw4bnds221a');
    
            res.cookie('token', token, {
                httpOnly: true,
            });
            res.render('home1', {token: token})

auth.js middleware code:
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

function auth(req, res, next) {

    try {
        const token = req.cookies.token;
        console.log(token)

        if(!token) return res.status(401).json({error: "Unauthorized"});
        const verified = jwt.verify(token, 'gmndshhrjvjhsw4bnds221a');

        req.user = verified.user;
        next();
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(401).json({
            error: "Unauthorized"
        })
    }
}

module.exports = auth;
```

localStorage received the token on home page but it showed unauthorized:
[image: Handlebarsjs Unauthorized picture]

Comment: If the token is stored in the browser's localStorage then it is _not_ in a cookie, but your server is trying to obtain it from `req.cookies`.

Comment: It also store in the Cookies as well

Comment: The one stored in Cookies is as same as the one stored in localStorage but when it check in middleware, it return Undefined

Comment: It seems like you are not using the token in localStorage. Can you confirm that the token is in the cookies with your request?

Comment: Yes the token is in the cookies